# Create a sumary list of maps in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy

From this sample list of maps;

```
def Assets = [
   [year: 2018, valueA:10, value:15],
   [year: 2018, valueA:15, value:25],
   [year: 2019, valueA:11, value:35],
   [year: 2020, valueA:17, value:2],
   [year: 2020, valueA:18, value:5],
   [year: 2021, valueA:10, value:25],
   [year: 2018, valueA:15, value:20]
]
```

I want to create a summary list that only includes unique years and averages the values for equal years i.e produce this result;

```
SummaryAssets = [
   [year: 2018, valueA:13, value:20],
   [year: 2019, valueA:11, value:35],
   [year: 2020, valueA:18, value:4],
   [year: 2021, valueA:10, value:25]
]
```

The only way I can think to do this to first find and create a list of the uniques years. Then based on these years:

1. Count the number of instances of each unique year
2. Sum valueA for each instance of a year
3. Sum valueB for each instance of a year
4. Divide each sum by the count of repeat instances
5. Write the results to the new SummaryAssets list

This seems cumbersome. Is there a more groovy way of doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use `groupBy` but otherwise do the equivalent of what you suggest:

```
def Assets = [
  [year: 2018, valueA:10, value:15],
  [year: 2018, valueA:15, value:25],
  [year: 2019, valueA:11, value:35],
  [year: 2020, valueA:17, value:2],
  [year: 2020, valueA:18, value:5],
  [year: 2021, valueA:10, value:25],
  [year: 2018, valueA:15, value:20]
]

def SummaryAssets = Assets.groupBy{ it.year }.collect{
  def v = it.value
  def avgForKey = { k -> [k, v[k].sum().div(v.size()).round()] }
  [year: it.key] + (v*.keySet().sum() - 'year').collectEntries(avgForKey)
}

assert SummaryAssets == [
  ['year':2018, 'valueA':13, 'value':20],
  ['year':2019, 'valueA':11, 'value':35],
  ['year':2020, 'valueA':18, 'value':4],
  ['year':2021, 'valueA':10, 'value':25]
]
```

Comment: Or `def avgForKey = { k -> [k, (v[k].sum()/v.size()).round()] }` if you prefer.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I try to execute this. I think I can see what should be happening but i cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: What version of Groovy are you using? I only tried 2.5.3 and master.

Comment: The system I am working on is 2.4.14, it's not possible for me to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, `round` for `BigDecimal` was added in 2.5. For Groovy 2.4 you can replace `round()` with `setScale(0, HALF_UP)`. You'll need an import: `import static java.math.RoundingMode.*`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One more question, how do I sort the summary list based on the year (earliest to latest)?

Comment: `SummaryAssets.sort{ it.year }`